# Use simple JavaScript in an ionic application

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, accordion

I am using ionic to build hybrid app for mobile phones. I have a card type layout in div tag and want to change the functionality of a div to be clickable just like accordion in bootstrap. Where can I put the JS code? Do I need a separate file for the code or need to add it to existing file? (like app.js or controller.js or services.js)

I have tried to put it in app.js but not working.

Comment: each and every page should have a controller name. check what is your controller name for that page and write code in that controller block

Answer (score 0):

you can use in html page also using script tag, or you can keep that code into related controller.js. best way is controller.